# How can i convert a point cloud data `(x, y, z)` into a depth map where `(x, y)` has depth `z`?

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision, physics, mesh

I got point cloud data in the form of `[(x, y, z) , (norm_x, norm_y, norm_z)]` in a text file. I am trying to convert this into a png or jpg image file where any points intensity corresponds to its depth `(z)`.

here is how an stl 3d file looks like (left). On the right is what i am trying to make.
[image]

Thank you all for taking time to read this.

Comment: In a depth map, x and y are pixel positions, not x and y of the 3D point. To generate a depth map you typically project the 3d points and remember the for each pixel the point with the lowest depth. E.g. the depth buffer of an opengl rendered scene. Probably open3d has some functions for doing that.

Comment: @Micka is right. You can use `render_to_depth_image` from Open3D

Comment: considering i am using top view only for constructing depth map, do i still need to project the points? 

also for projection, what camera matrix values and rotation vector should i be using ?

Comment: @AliWaqas yes, you still need to project them. In the pinhole camera model, the projection of (x,y,z) is not simply (x,y) (check eq 1 in https://hedivision.github.io/Pinhole.html). So, you can write your own renderer and that would be a great exercise. But if you are only looking for an answer, you can make use of the existing functionalities of Open3D (or any other library). You can check this tutorial to see how you can set camera angle and render depth maps: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/visualization/customized_visualization.html

Comment: @AliWaqas No, you do not need to project the points.  [See below.]

Answer (score -1):

```js
x_min = -2
x_max = 2
y_min = -1
y_max = 1
z_min = 0
z_max = 1

dx = x_max - x_min
dy = y_max - y_min
dz = z_max - z_min

Ps = []
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) Ps.push([x_min + Math.random()*dx, y_min + Math.random()*dy, z_min + Math.random()*dz])

width = canvas.width
height = canvas.height
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
context.setFillColor('#000000')
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
imagedata = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
data = imagedata.data
w = width - 1
h = height - 1
for (P of Ps) {
  col = Math.round(((P[0] - x_min)/dx)*w)
  row = Math.round(((y_max - P[1])/dy)*h)
  val = ((P[2] - z_min)/dz)*255
  i = 4*(width*row + col)
  if (data[i] < val) data[i] = data[i + 1] = data[i + 2] = val
}
context.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0)
a.href = canvas.toDataURL()
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas>HTML5</canvas><br><a id=a>Download</a>
```

Comment: Note: (norm_x, norm_y, norm_z) is unused.

Comment: can you explain your code?

Comment: Imagine a map of a city on which each block is colored a shade of gray (black/white -> minimum/maximum height) corresponding to the tallest building on the block.  My code creates such a map where a “block” is a pixel, “height” is z-value, and a “building” is a point.

Comment: @AliWaqas Is my explanation clear?

Comment: No. Can you back it up with some theory?